# get all selected items from wpf checkbox list give me error

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have `ListBox` with checked box as following, and it binding its data from `SQL server database`. I want to get selected items value When I run this but I got this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 
>   'System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox'.

This is code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="NameColumnTemplate">
        <CheckBox Height="20" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" Content="{Binding Path=PermissionDescription}" Tag="{Binding PermissionID}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12,12,136,21" Name="lstEmployees" 
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Tables[0]}"  
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NameColumnTemplate}" 
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" removed="{x:Null}"
         BorderBrush="#FFAD7F30"  
         SelectionChanged="lst_SelectionChanged" CheckBox.Click="lst_SelectionChanged"/>

    <Button Content="listbox" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="214,207,0,0" Name="btnShowSelectedItems" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnShowSelectedItems_Click" />
</Grid>

public Window2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // bind data 
    lstEmployees.DataContext = SelJobsCat();
}

private void btnShowSelectedItems_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (CheckBox item in lstEmployees.Items)
    {
        if (item.IsChecked == true)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show((item.Content + " is checked."));
        }
    }
}

private void lst_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource is CheckBox)
    {
        lstEmployees.SelectedItem = e.OriginalSource;
    }

    if (lstEmployees.SelectedItem == null) return;

    Console.WriteLine(lstEmployees.SelectedIndex);
    Console.WriteLine(((CheckBox)lstEmployees.SelectedItem).IsChecked);
 }
```

Where is my error please, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ListBox.Items` is set to a `DataTable` in your XAML (`ItemsSource="{Binding Tables[0]}"`), so looping through `ListBox.Items` is looping through `DataRowView` objects, not the `CheckBox` objects

Your best bet is to add a `bool` column to your `DataContext` (the `DataTable`) so you can bind `CheckBox.IsChecked` to it.

You could also use the [ItemContainerGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.aspx) to generate the XAML item generated for the data item, however this may not be accurate because `ListBoxes` are virtualized by default, which means if you don't bind a value to the `DataContext`, it won't necessarily be kept.

To work with WPF the right way, you really should add a bool value to the `DataContext`

Comment: Thanks a lot Rachel, I add a bool column to my DataContext , & now its work fine.

Comment: @Rachel If you are good in WPf then plz try to give me a solution on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402056/how-to-use-grid-inside-grid-nested-grid-on-devexpress-tools-in-wpf