# auto check to items in wpf check Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a check list box in wpf. With some email ids populated using `public ObservableCollection<BoolStringClass> TheList { get; set; }` method at runtime.

When user save the record the selecetd email ids are saved in database(123@gmail.com;456@yahoo.co.in;789@rediff.com).. and so on with comma separated.

Now when I want to reload the data on to controls from database, how can I keep checked the items stored in database ?  In windows forms its easy to achieve this, but how this can be done in wpf?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21193608/1187982).  Perhaps that will answer your question.

Comment: What is wpf stopping to you which you can perform with Winform?

Comment: Joshua, the answer u provided is for geting the selected item in listbox.

Comment: Joshua, the answer u provided is for geting the selected item in listbox. I want that I have a datatable with thosed items that are present in list box also. I am looking for something like this    foreach( var o in listEmailsIds.Items)
                    {
                        string v = o.ToString();
                        if (emailID.ToString() == v) //emailID is from database
                        {
                          v.ischecked = true;
                        }

Answer (score 2):

Better have the ObservableCollection of EmailItem and have string and IsSelected property. Bind the collection to check box list. And Set IsSelected based on whether they are saved in database

Comment: This should go as comment, check the question.

Comment: @HariPrasad Why?  Does this not answer the question?  Admittedly, it would be better if this answer went into more depth (and maybe provided an example) but it *is* an answer.

Comment: can you provide a piece of code or an example for I want that I have a datatable with thosed items that are present in list box also. I am looking for something like this foreach( var o in listEmailsIds.Items) { string v = o.ToString(); if (emailID.ToString() == v) //emailID is from database { v.ischecked = true; }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381741/get-all-selected-items-from-wpf-checkbox-list-give-me-error This has example with datatable instead of class, but using same approach to add the IsChecked column to the datatable

Comment: Guys I am looking for similar as marked correct in the link below answer but in WPF C# for checklistbox http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185770/programatically-check-an-item-in-checkboxlist-where-text-is-equal-to-what-i-want